# execute several programs in batch and generate a single report

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to generate a single report when running in a bat many [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) tools, and the data within "report" is organized. How can I do it (.bat loop)

Example: diag.bat (the problem is > and >>)

```
start cports.exe /shtml > "Report.html"
start USBDeview.exe /shtml /shtml >> "Report.html"
```

Example: diag.bat (without > and >>) that's ok but 2 reports

```
start cports.exe /shtml "Report.html"
start USBDeview.exe /shtml "Report2.html"
```

Thanks

Comment: Remove `Start /wait` from each line and add full paths to the program. Probably remove `exit`. See my summary here of how to start programs - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40371443/what-do-all-commands-in-batch-mean-and-do.

Comment: update with your specifications and error. I can not generate the report. All the exe files are in the same folder

Comment: Do they write to standard out. Generally programs that do are console programs not graphical programs.

Comment: the problem is > and >>. This is why I need a loop. The option /WAIT is not a problem (Is used only to wait for the execution of a program to start the next one. But it can be removed.)

Comment: Programs wait anyway. Start main use is to NOT wait. Start does a shellexecute. That means lots of stuff. When someone bothers to look stuff up and point out stuff to you you ignore it. Reread my previous comments.

Comment: I do not ignore it, and I appreciate your observations. But they do not solve my problem. I would appreciate your answers being specifically oriented to the solution of the problem.

Comment: Then I'll be brief. It will never work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the single reports are html, all you need is a new framing html file which includes the other ones. To ease this they should be in one place. The creation of the file is a bit tedious as all tags have to be escaped with a caret.

```
@Echo off
Set "NirSoft=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\WSCC3\NirSoft Utilities"
Set "Out=%USERPROFILE%\Documents

PushD "%NirSoft%"
cports.exe    /shtml "%Out%\Report_cports.html"
USBDeview.exe /shtml "%Out%\Report_USBDeview.html"
PopD

> "%Out%\Report.html" (
Echo:^<!DOCTYPE html^>
Echo:^<html^>
Echo:^<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"^>^</script^>
Echo:^<body^>
Echo:^<div w3-include-html="Report_cports.html"^>^</div^>
Echo:^<div w3-include-html="Report_USBDeview.html"^>^</div^>
Echo:^<script^>
Echo:w3IncludeHTML^(^);
Echo:^</script^>
Echo:^</body^>
Echo:^</html^>
)
```

Comment: Generates individual reports well, but not the final report (all together)

Comment: It did work here, are you shure the batch is copied as is except inserting your own path values? Do you get an error or strange screen output? Eventually insert a pause command at the end.

Comment: If you use an editor not a browser to view the Report.html, what do you see?

Comment: I just rechecked with an additional NirSoft-Tool (WakeMeOnLan) It works here. The only reason I could think of is you may not be able to acces `http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js` which is necessary for the embedding.

Comment: Tried with frameset and html5 embed but the results where ugly. The above batch gives the best results here. So without further feedback I see this as a solution just for me :-(

Comment: w3data.js is fine. Content of Report.html <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
<body>
<div w3-include-html="Report_cports.html"></div>
<div w3-include-html="Report_USBDeview.html"></div>
<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I tested successfully with firefox version 50.0.2.

Comment: You are right. But why can not i see it in chrome 54.0.2840.99 (only firefox). Please delete the part where the browser opens automatically. Thank you

Comment: So even with restrictions there is an answer, would be glad if you checked it.

Comment: Ty and I did 16 hours ago ;-)

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much. But your script I can not use it as it is for an audit and there are some NirSoft Utilities that open up when I launch the batch and the final report does not complete. that's not what I want.

Comment: If the Report files are already generated and have distinct names there isno need to run the nirsoft tools only get the reports accumulated.